# PostgreSQL sequence being reset?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-database

On a regular occasion, my Django webapps produce SQL errors on M2M tables.

*Each time it turns out the ID sequence is reset to a value within the range of existing rows.*

The app performs normal SQL queries such as:

```
INSERT INTO "myapp_project" ("name") VALUES ('test1') RETURNING "myapp_project"."id"'
```

which cause errors such as:

```
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "myapp_project_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(29) already exists.
```

Then it turns out that the `myapp_project_id_seq` is pointing to an old ID number:

```
select currval('myapp_project_id_seq')
29
```

Which can then be reset by using:

```
select setval('myapp_project_id_seq', (select max(id) from myapp_project))
```

However, I can't explain why this is happening. It typically happens on M2M tables in Django. In this case, a normal table with admin-only input. Can someone enlighten me about this?

Comment: You are almost certainly inserting id's manually somewhere. Where I couldn't say, but that is where you should start looking.

Comment: Interesting. @RichardHuxton: does inserting ID's also cause the sequence to be reset? Or would that mean that it was messed up before?

Comment: no what's happening is you insert rows 1,2,3 using the sequence then do 4,5 manually. Next auto-generated id will be 4 because it doesn't know what you've done. That gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

This typically happens when you (or somebody) sometimes write values to `id` explicitly, instead of getting values from the sequence (by default or with `nextval()`).

Your repair code is missing a pair of parentheses.

```
SELECT setval('myapp_project_id_seq', (SELECT max(id) FROM myapp_project));
```

This is a tiny bit shorter & cheaper while doing the same, exactly:

```
SELECT setval('myapp_project_id_seq', max(id)) FROM myapp_project;
```